# How to add calculated fields inside subdocuments without using unwind?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a simple solution to add a field to a subdocument without using `$unwind` and `$group`.
I need only to calculate the sum and the size of a nested subdocuments and show it in a new field.
This is my starting collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
  "subDoc": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "subArray": [1,2,3]
     },
     {
       "b": 2
     }
   ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
  "subDoc": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "subArray": [4,5,6]
     },
     {
       "b": 2
     },
     {
       "c": 3,
       "subArray": [8,8,8]
     }
  ]
}
```

And this is my desired result, where I've added `sum` (sum of `subArray`) and `size` (number of elements in `subArray`):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
  "subDoc": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "subArray": [1,2,3],
       "sum": 6,
       "size": 3
     },
     {
       "b": 2
       "sum": 0,
       "size": 0
     }
   ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
  "subDoc": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "subArray": [4,5,6],
       "sum": 15,
       "size": 3
     },
     {
       "b": 2,
       "sum": 0,
       "size": 0
     },
     {
       "c": 3,
       "subArray": [8,8],
       "sum": 16,
       "size": 2
     }
  ] 
}
```

I know how to obtain this result using `$unwind` and then `$group`, but I'd like to know if there is any other way (or a better way!) to achieve the same result. I've tried using `$addFields` and `$map` without success.

Working playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fK8t6SLlOHa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `subDoc` array
- `$sum` to get total of `subArray` array of numbers
- `$ifNull` to check if field is not present or null then return empty array because $size operator only allows array input
- `$size` to get total elements in `subArray` array
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with new added fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      subDoc: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subDoc",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                sum: { $sum: "$$this.subArray" },
                size: {
                  $size: { $ifNull: ["$$this.subArray", []] }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2W6B8oyJEOS)